# Chosing a package is according to different matric?

Tags: pcb, resistors, inductor, surface-mount

I need some part with package **0402** .
Looking at `Mouser.com`, the only packages I get for this part are **"0402 (1005 metric)"**.

I then check the size of it and its **not 4x2mm** but  *1x0.5mm*.

For example [this](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ABRACON/ATFC-0402HQ-3N9B-T/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsg%252by3WlYCkU2vsZPp70J0ayH9Ev9U0YhU%3D) inductor that I need in 0402 .

How do you make sure its 0402 ? why there is no 0402 for inductors ?

Comment: Which do you need, an 0402 package OR a 4x2mm part? A metric package that is 4mmx2mm would be a "4020 metric" package.

Comment: Also, 4020 metric would translate to a 1608.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0402 means it is 40mils x 20 mils (0.04" x 0.02") which is essentially 1mm x 0.5mm.

It can't be exactly both, obviously, so chances are it will be 'hard' metric and the inch dimensions are approximate.

Looking, for example, at [this](https://www.johansontechnology.com/downloads/jti-cat-rf-ind.pdf) datasheet we see that these particular Johanson RF inductors are hard metric:

[image]

Comment: thanks, not sure I get you, so what does 1005 metric means? is it 0402 ?

Comment: Yes, they refer to the same package. '1005 metric' is 1mm x 0.5mm which is 0402 in inches.

Comment: i am confused now on Mouser. Lets say I have in my Eagle design a resistor of 0402. That means on Mouser I am looking for "case code 0402 in mm" or "0402 in- in" ? there are both :)

Comment: Aside from one 10K part which appears to be a Mouser data entry error, 0402 metric is 01005 inch -- 0.4mm x 0.2mm which- if you can imagine- that is REALLY TINY . Rohm even has 03015 metric  which is 0.3 x 0.15mm, even smaller. For hand work I find inch 0402 about as small as you want to go. Search in disties but always look at the real datasheets not just the distributor data before ordering- there are more errors in the distie tables. And yes, having both metric and inch 0402 is potentially confusing. Metric 0402 comes in reels of 20,000 usually, inch in 10K reels.

Comment: At the begining for you previous answer you said the opposite, I know you have good intentions but you made me confused even more. You first line in the answer is different from this comment's first line. Here you say its mm there you said its 0.04x0.02inches.

Comment: 0402 inch = 0105 metric  ...................................

01005 inch = 0402 metric

Comment: Those legacy "inch" based case sizes are called EIA Case Size. Unfortunately a lot of surface mount work was established using the EIA case sizes before metric case sizes were commonly used.